# Windows Batch Script VLOOKUP Output Assistance

Tags: windows, batch-file, vlookup

Data File 1:

```
Account,Department,Location,Amount  
10000,DEPT_100,LOC_101,1000  
20000,DEPT_200,LOC_200,2000  
30000,DEPT_300,LOC_300,3000  
40000,DEPT_400,LOC_400,4000
```

Data File 2:

```
Account,Department,Location,Amount  
10000,DEPT_100,LOC_100,1000  
20000,DEPT_200,LOC_200,2000  
30000,DEPT_300,LOC_300,3000  
40000,DEPT_400,LOC_400,4000
```

**Desired Output (Data File 1 - Data File 2 - Difference:)**

```
10000,DEPT_100,LOC_101,1000 - 10000,DEPT_100,LOC_100,1000 - Difference: LOC_100
```

Current Output:

```
10000,DEPT_100,LOC_100,1000 - 10000DEPT_100LOC_1001000,
```

```batch-file
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "file1=input_file1.csv"
set "file2=input_file2.csv"
set "output_file=differences_output.csv"

:: Concatenate columns in both files
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4,* delims=," %%a in ("%file1%") do (
    set "line=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d - %%a%%b%%c%%d,%%e"
    echo !line!>>temp_file1.csv
)

for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4,* delims=," %%a in ("%file2%") do (
    set "line=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d - %%a%%b%%c%%d,%%e"
    echo !line!>>temp_file2.csv
)

:: Perform VLOOKUP
findstr /v /g:temp_file1.csv temp_file2.csv > %output_file%

:: Loop through records in the output file and display differences
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-5,* delims=-," %%a in ("%output_file%") do (
    echo Record: %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e - Difference: %%f
)

:: Cleanup temporary files
del temp_file1.csv
del temp_file2.csv

echo Done. Differences written to %output_file%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm... I think you should first define what "File difference" means...

However, if you have two files with the *same number* of lines that match one-by-one and want to know which fields in the second file *don't appears in the first file*, then this solution do the trick:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< test2.txt (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (test1.txt) do (
      set /P "line2="
      set "diffs= !line2:,= ! "
      for %%b in (%%a) do set "diffs=!diffs: %%b =  !"
      if "!diffs!" neq "     " (
         echo %%a - !line2! - Difference:!diffs!
      )
   )
)
```

Output:

```
10000,DEPT_100,LOC_101,1000 - 10000,DEPT_100,LOC_100,1000 - Difference:   LOC_100
```

Be aware that there are several undefined details or limitations. For example: the lines can *not* have spaces, nor asterisks, nor question-marks, nor exclamation-marks. There must be 4 fields in each line, precisely. And others...